# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type (JpaRepository and Java Config)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception, spring-data-jpa

the last few hours i tried to get my sample web app started, but i get always this `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` :(

I have the `@EnableJpaRepositories` and i also tried it with `@JpaRepository`!


I created a github repository, there you can see the whole code. I hope this is ok for you.

> [github repo with my code](https://github.com/m1well/spring_hibernate_sample_webapp)

But here are some Codelines:

JPA Reposository (package: root.repository):

```
public interface AppUserRepository extends JpaRepository<AppUser, String> {
  AppUser findByUsername(String username);
}
```

App User (package: root.model):

```
public class AppUser {

private String uuid;
private String username;
private String password;
private String passwordConfirm;
private Set<AppAuthority> appAuthorities;

getter / setter
```

AppConfig (package: root.config):

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"de.m1well.spring.webapp.sample"})
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class AppConfig  {

}
```

PersistenceConfig (package: root.config):

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("de.m1well.spring.webapp.sample.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class PersistenceConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
  // create datasource
  return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
  // create LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
  return em;
}

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
  return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
  // hibernate properties
  return properties;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf)         {
  // create TransactionManager  
  return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
  return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

}
```

WebConfig (package: root.config):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
  // create ViewResolver
  return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
  // create MessageSource
  return source;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/");
}

}
```

Stacktrace
:

```
25-Oct-2017 07:27:47.861 SCHWERWIEGEND [localhost-startStop-4]org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'appUserRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'de.m1well.spring.webapp.sample.repository.AppUserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4851)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1853)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'appUserRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'de.m1well.spring.webapp.sample.repository.AppUserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.obtainBeanInstanceFromFactory(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:389)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
at de.m1well.spring.webapp.sample.config.WebSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$702d5227.userDetailsServiceImpl(<generated>)
at de.m1well.spring.webapp.sample.config.WebSecurityConfig.configureGlobal(WebSecurityConfig.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:701)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'de.m1well.spring.webapp.sample.repository.AppUserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
... 46 more
```

Comment: A full stacktrace is better than an isolated message.

Comment: i added the stacktrace of this exception. i also changed the mysql connector from v6 to v5.

Comment: changed now from JpaRepository to EntityManager... always the same error `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'de.m1well.spring.webapp.sample.repository.AppUserRepository'` :(

Comment: changed now from java-config to xml-config - always the same error ......

Answer (score 0):

Your repositories are not annotated as a bean (in this case a Repository bean).

```
@Repository
public interface AppUserRepository extends JpaRepository<AppUser, String> {
  AppUser findByUsername(String username);
}
```

This should do the trick

Comment: i tried that too, but doesn't change anything. but now i got this error: `NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/index/CandidateComponentsIndexLoader`

Comment: and i thought with `@EnableJpaRepositories("de.m1well.spring.webapp.sample.repository")` - i don't need `@Reposiroty`?

Answer (score 0):

May be it is because of the Component scan's entered basePackage. Try this:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "de.m1well.spring.webapp.sample")
```

I hope It can resolve your problem.